# Need help finding pin assignments

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am trying to output sound on a FPGA through its stereo out. In Verilog I've declared "stereo" as an output and have some code to generate sound. However, I cannot find the pin assignments for the stereo out to assign to "speaker".

I'm using [DE2i-150 FPGA Development Kit](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=11&No=529).

Comment: Stereo is controlled by microprocessor, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours Board's FPGA Doesn't have any circuit to play music so it uses an Audio codec to do this job. It must be noted that the board contain Audio CODEC "Realtek ALC272VA3-GR" therefore its gives sound so i think you first see the connection of this IC(Audio codec) to your FPGA,then give input to those pin which connect to this Codec IC.

The link to your Audio Codec Datasheet is [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?langid=1&pfid=27&level=5&conn=4&prodid=171&DownTypeID=1&GetDown=false&Downloads=true)

Answer (score 1):

The board has an audio output and audio codec, however these are connected to the Atom CPU and not the FPGA.

You could transfer the audio to the CPU and have the CPU play the audio, or add an extra DAC expansion board. Another option (if high fidelity isn't needed) would be to do a PWM output from the FPGA, and low-pass that.